# Lewis Structures and electron distribution with oxygen atom

Tags: lewis-structure

I am a novice in chemistry.

I don’t understand the way Lewis structure and how electrons are shared between elements.

For instance [image]

As we know, Oxygen has six valence electrons that means it has **3 lone pairs**.

So when oxygen wants to form a covalent bond, one of its valence electron should participate in the covalent bond.

In the picture above, however, even though that oxygen use one of its valence electron, we can clearly see that it still has 3 lone pairs. Well, they should be five electron Instead of 6.

In my interpretation, it should be like this ⬇️:

[image]

Could you explain this?

Comment: Oxygen is a special case, there are so many Youtube videos on Lewis dot structures. Just use the keywords on Youtube.

Comment: In the Lewis formalism, an electron has been *added* to the valence shells of two oxygens in $\ce{NO3-}$, meaning they have *seven* electrons at their disposal. Likewise, the central nitrogen has one electron *removed* leaving it with four. To make this clear, a proper Lewis depiction should include formal charges; the two oxygens on the end of an $\ce{N-O}$ single bond should be $\ce{O-}$ while the nitrogen should be $\ce{N+}$. The sum of formal charges must equal the compound’s overall charge.